# For how long and how cold should I perform ethanol/isopropanol precipitations of RNA or DNA?

Tags: biochemistry, nucleic-acids

Precipitating nucleic acids using either isopropanol or ethanol is a very common operation, and I've read some very different protocols on the duration and temperature the precipitation should be performed.

I've seen anything from precipitating at room-temperature and centrifugating immediately without any delay to precipitating at -20 °C over night in various protocols.

Is there any published data about the influence of duration and temperature on the yield of the nucleic acid precipitation?

Comment: I think the folklore is influenced by how much nucleic acid you are working with. As @Daniel Standage suggests, some conditions wouldn't be influenced by anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always did mine at -80 C, but I never compared the results to other protocols (*I don't fix what's not broken*). But, I was curious about the same thing, so I looked around. I found one paper discussing this: [Paithankar and Prasad, Nuc Acids Res 19(6):1346 (1991)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC333871/pdf/nar00242-0172.pdf)

It shows that at low concentrations, EtOH at RT actually outperforms the precipitations at both 4 C and  dry ice/ethanol bath. That difference is quite big at 100ng/ml DNA and lost when there is more than 10 ug/ml DNA. For typical extractions, based on this data, I'd do it at RT.

On the other hand, [Hilario and Mackay](http://books.google.com/books?id=3fDZqwC8ORwC&pg=PA11&dq=effect+of+temperature+on+ethanol+DNA+precipitation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rNV0T_yxD8600AHbyeyiDQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=effect%20of%20temperature%20on%20ethanol%20DNA%20precipitation&f=false) say in their book that:

> for genomic DNA isolation, different DNA precipitation temperatures
>   and incubation times have little effect on recovery rates. One can
>   directly centrifuge after adding ethanol without the -20 C incubation,
>   and, it -20 C ethanol is not available, room temperature ethanol can
>   be used.

They do not, however, provide any citation for that statement.

Answer (score 2):

As a first year molecular biology student, I did a class project on this very question:  trying to see if buffer temperature had an effect on yield during DNA precipitation. This is a far cry from peer reviewed research, but my finding was that there was no significant effect for a wide range of temperatures.