# DNA extraction from agarose gel

Tags: dna, gel-electrophoresis

Because DNA is soluble in water, is it possible to extract PCR product by dissolving excised gel containing the DNA band of desired length in water, mashing the gel piece with a pestle, centrifuging it and then pipetting out the supernatant ?

Comment: If you mash it with a pestle, you'll likely break the DNA. You can use a low melting point gel and mild heating followed by centrifugation to extract DNA.

Comment: why not use this? (http://www.qiagen.com/products/catalog/sample-technologies/dna-sample-technologies/dna-cleanup/qiaquick-gel-extraction-kit) or a similar product? I have used it many many times and it can be done very easily!

Comment: @Bez - Well, that would cost around 1-2$ per sample, correct ?

Comment: @AnuragMishra indeed, however, there might be delivery charges but some times institutes bulk buy and sell it in their own stores and their prices are less and sometimes there are institute based purchase pages which sell the products at the discounted price. ps I'm not promoting any brand or products here and I just put it up as a point of reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (and I have done it uncounted number of times) - the method is called "Freeze and squeeze". What you basically do is to run the gel, cut out the band of interest (be careful with the UV light, it causes damage to your DNA and also sunburns, so wear appropriate shielding for your face), dissolve it in a buffer, then freeze it in liquid nitrogen (or the -70°C, doesn't matter) and centrifuge it at room temperature for 10 minutes. During this time the ice melts and the agarose pellets at the bottom. Take the supernatant, do a ethanol precipitation (with glycogen when you only have little DNA) and you have nice and clean DNA. No need for expensive kits and is done approximately in 2 hours.

You can find a very nice and detailed protocol here: "[Elution of DNA from Agarose Gels](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906161340/http://personal.bgsu.edu/~gangz/Page099-103_Elution_of_DNA_from_Agarose_Gels.pdf)" (The rest of the [handbook](http://web.archive.org/web/20151003090249/http://personal.bgsu.edu/%7Egangz/EFB601.htm) is also very useful).

Comment: Yes, we used to call this method 'freeze-squeeze'.

Comment: Right, I added this. Useful method and always amazed our new masters students. "What, no columns?" :-)

Comment: But, how will Qiagen make money if people know how to do this?

Comment: I have just put a comment about the Qiagen product. I guess ease of use of kits has made me very dependent. Its always great to find alternative methods to use. Many thanks for the method Chris.

Comment: @Chris instead of ethidium bromide use for DNA detection with UV, you can use SafeView Nucleic Acid Stain by NBS Biologicals, which uses fluorescence excitation maxima at approx 290-320nm, emitting at 515nm so its non-UV detection and it is very sensitive in my experience and safe too!

Comment: @Bez: Excitation 290-320 means that it needs to be excited in UV-B (which can cause DNA damage). The only difference is the emission wavelength which is green not orange/red. And that they claim that they are safer than EtBr.

Comment: @MattDMo I don't think that companies like Qiagen are in danger of going bancrupt any time in the near future. :-) Besides that, I started to use this, when we had problems of isolating short DNA pieces from the gel with columns. Subsequently I dropped columns for this work.

Comment: Extracting from PA gels is more pain. In such cases electroelution is also an option

Comment: PA gels are not dissolving when they are subjected to heat. But we rarely use them.

Comment: Ethanol precipitation is a overnight step, right ?

Comment: @AnuragMishra No not necessarily. Have a look at [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/for-how-long-and-how-cold-should-i-perform-ethanol-isopropanol-precipitations-of) and [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15236/isopropanol-precipitation-of-dna-duration-and-magnitude-of-cold-storage/15237#15237) article here at stackexchange. They go into detail. In short: Overnight brings no advantage.

Comment: The centrifugation after keeping the buffer+gel slices at -70C should be at how many RPM ?

Comment: @AnuragMishra At maximum speed, 14.000 or whatever your benchtop centrifuge can do.

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old post, but how does this method compare to the qiagen spin columns? When using spin columns I always have terrible 260/230 (< 0.1), suggesting that significant agarose is carried over. My yield also seems poor, but this could be related to the amount of DNA used in the gel. I usually do gel purification on PCR products and get <500 ng of DNA, but I can't calculate a percent yield because I don't know how much PCR product was there. But other people in the lab use the columns to gel purify 100 ug of digested DNA and get 50% yield, but don't tell me the 260/230.

Comment: @user137 Ihave never compared this systematically with spin columns. And I have mostly used this technique with digested DNA which was subsequently cloned (so mostly digested PCR fragments or pieces of DNA), so I generally had not much material in the beginning. Recovery was ok and cloning with this purified DNA was also not a problem.